# Sequelize many to many brings many objects instead of one with array

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, backend

I want to make a shopping cart for my project, and I have these three tables/models:

User:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const alias = 'User';

const cols = {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    first_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    last_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    type_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
}

const config = {
    tableName: 'users',
    timestamps: false
}

const User = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.Product, {
        as: 'owner',
        foreignKey: 'owner_id',
        timestamps: false
    });

    User.belongsTo(models.UserType, {
        as: 'type',
        foreignKey: 'type_id',
        timestamps: false
    });

    User.belongsToMany(models.Product, {
        as: 'cart',
        through: 'Product_Cart',
        foreignKey: 'user_id'
    })
}

return User;
}
```

Product:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataType) => {
const alias = 'Product';

const cols = {
    id: {
        type: DataType.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    title: {
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    price: {
        type: DataType.FLOAT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    owner_id: {
        type: DataType.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    image: {
        type: DataType.STRING,
    }
}

const config = {
    tableName: 'products',
    timestamps: false
}

const Product = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

Product.associate = (models) => {
    Product.belongsTo(models.User, {
        as: 'owner',
        foreignKey: 'owner_id',
        timestamps: false
    });

    Product.belongsToMany(models.User, {
        as: 'cart',
        through: 'Product_Cart',
        foreignKey: 'product_id'
    });
}

return Product;
}
```

Product_Cart:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataType) => {
const alias = 'Product_Cart';

const cols = {
    id: {
        type: DataType.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    user_id: {
        type: DataType.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    product_id: {
        type: DataType.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    quantity: {
        type: DataType.INTEGER
    }
}

const config = {
    tableName: 'product_cart',
    timestamps: false
}

const ProductCart = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

return ProductCart;
}
```

As you can see, there's a M:N relationship between Product and User, since a User may have many products in their's product cart, and a product may be in many user's product cart.

The thing is, when I run the following code:

```
const user = await User.findAll({
    where: {
        id: 1
    },
    raw: true,
    include: ['cart'],
    nest: true
});
```

I get this:

```
    [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "asdfasdf@asdfasd.com",
    "first_name": "Nacho",
    "last_name": "García",
    "password": "1123123qasdfasdf",
    "type_id": 1,
    "cart": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "ASD",
      "price": 123,
      "owner_id": 1,
      "image": "ASDFASDFA",
      "Product_Cart": {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "product_id": 1,
        "quantity": 5
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "asdfasdf@asdfasd.com",
    "first_name": "Nacho",
    "last_name": "García",
    "password": "1123123qasdfasdf",
    "type_id": 1,
    "cart": {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "GAGAGA",
      "price": 123,
      "owner_id": 1,
      "image": "asdfoijasdoi",
      "Product_Cart": {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "product_id": 2,
        "quantity": 15
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But I really need this:

```
    {
  "id": 1,
  "email": "asdfasdf@asdfasd.com",
  "first_name": "Nacho",
  "last_name": "García",
  "password": "1123123qasdfasdf",
  "type_id": 1,
  "cart": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "ASD",
      "price": 123,
      "owner_id": 1,
      "image": "ASDFASDFA",
      "Product_Cart": {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "product_id": 1,
        "quantity": 5
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "GAGAGA",
      "price": 123,
      "owner_id": 1,
      "image": "asdfoijasdoi",
      "Product_Cart": {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "product_id": 2,
        "quantity": 15
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How could I get to sequelize send me that object as an array? I know I could turn the original one into the one I'd like to have, but I want to know if there's any way for sequelize to send me it directly like that (which I think is the logic way of recieving the object).

Comment: you should remove the `raw: true`. this is to disable sequelize formatting like grouping etc.  Also, to get the object at top-level, try using `findByPk` or `findOne`.